# How do I get this code to work?

Tags: c++, arrays, function, pointers

Struggling with this, can't seem to get it to work. Here is what I need to do:

1.Ask the user how many weeks were in the landscaping season this year.

2.Dynamically create an array of double floating point data that can be used to store the sales for each week of the season.

3.Using a for loop, have the user enter in the sales data for the season.

4.Pass the array (and its size) into a function that will display all the sales for the weeks in a nice table.

5.Call another function that will take in the array as an argument and will total the sales for the season (returning the total to the main function).

6.Have the program tell the user the total sales for the season and the average sales per week.

7.After this delete the allocated memory and set the pointer to 0.

Any assistance helps always I don't quite understand functions, or pointers. and I've read about both a lot!!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;


int Weeks = 0;
double total;
double sales;
void SalesTable(int);
double Total (int, double[]);
double average;

int main()
{ 

   double Season[Weeks];

   cout << "How many weeks were in the landscaping season this year: ";
   cin >> Weeks;

   for (int i = 1; i<Weeks+1; i++)
   {
      cout << "Enter sales data for week " << i <<": ";
      cin >> sales;
   }

Season[Weeks]=sales;

SalesTable(Weeks);
Total(Weeks, Season);

average = total/Weeks;

cout << "The total sales for the season are: "<<setprecision(2)<<showpoint<<fixed<<total<<        endl;
cout << "The average weekly sales were: "<<setprecision(2)<<showpoint<<fixed<<average;
return 0;
}
void SalesTable(int Weeks)
{
for(int i = 1; i<Weeks+1; i++)
{
    cout << "Sales for week "<< i <<":" << sales <<endl;
}
}
double Total(int Weeks, double Season[])
{
for(int i = 1; i<Weeks+1; i++)
{
    total += Season[Weeks];
}
return total;
}
```

Comment: `double Season[Weeks];` ????

Comment: You write what you want to do, but not how much of your code actually works and where exactly you get stuck.

Comment: my functions not sure how to make them work and my array im not sure how to store the amt of weeks the user enters into it. and there is number 7 with the pointer not sure what to do with that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok , using pointer to double it will do what you need :

```
int Weeks = 0;
double total;
double sales;
void SalesTable(int, double*);
double Total (int, double*);
double average;
int main ()
{
    double *Season;
    cout << "How many weeks were in the landscaping season this year: ";
    cin >> Weeks;

            Season = new double [ Weeks ];

    for (int i = 1; i<Weeks+1; i++)
    {
       cout << "Enter sales data for week " << i <<": ";
       cin >> sales;
       Season[i-1]=sales;
    }



    SalesTable(Weeks, Season);
    Total(Weeks, Season);

    average = total/(double)Weeks;

    cout << "The total sales for the season are: "<<showpoint<<fixed<<total<<endl;
    cout << "The average weekly sales were: "<<showpoint<<fixed<<average;
    delete[] Season;
    return 0;
}

    void SalesTable(int Weeks,double *Season)
    {
        for(int i = 1; i<Weeks+1; i++)
        {
            cout << "Sales for week "<< i <<":" << Season[i-1]<<endl;
        }
    }

    double Total(int Weeks, double *Season)
    {
        for(int i = 1; i<Weeks+1; i++)
        {
            total += Season[i-1];
        }
        return total;
    }
```

Comment: only problem is I cant have a set amount of weeks it has to be open for the user to enter

Comment: Then it's better for you to use `vector` instead of arrays

Answer (score 0):

Since I can't comment yet, I'll post a new answer:

The code provided by T-D still doesn't work because of this: the print out for each sales week is always the same because it isn't accessing the elements inside of the Seasons array.

```
void SalesTable(int Weeks)
{
    for(int i = 1; i<Weeks+1; i++)
    {
        cout << "Sales for week "<< i <<":" << Season[i - 1] << endl;
    }
}
```

Also, to dynamically create an array which allows the user to control the size of the array at runtime use the following code:

```
double *season = new double[Weeks];
```

And because you dynamically created the array, you have to manually release its resources:

```
delete[] season;
```

Comment: I updated my answers many times, that's why I forgot to pass the parameter season to the function `SalesTable` , Now my last edit to my answer was by using pointers

Comment: You still need to delete the pointer at the end of the program's execution. Otherwise you would have a memory leak.

Comment: when i use double *season =.... i get error saying "array expression must have integral or unscoped enumeration type, not 'double'

Comment: What exactly is the code that you are trying to use? Is it:
    double *season = new double[Weeks];

Comment: @NoobCoder85 copy the edited answer I posted, it works , I tried it, it will do what you mentioned in your question

Comment: Everything works perfect now THANK YOU!! You saved me from many many hours of torment and also a lifetime hatred of programming!!!